# Unity Google Play Games real time messages on different objects

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, real-time, multiplayer

So i'm currently working on a game with unity, it's an air hockey.

But i have a problem to receive my messages on different objects.

So what i did, is when two players are in the same room, i create a bool to choose the main player.

The main player will receive just the message from the other player (mallet opponent), and the other player who is not the main player will receive messages of the main player and the pallet in his game.

So i came up with this:

```
public void OnRealTimeMessageReceived (bool isReliable, string senderId, byte[] data)
{
    string rawdata = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString (data);
    string[] slice = rawdata.Split (new string[] { ":" }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (MainPlayer == true) {

        if (slice [0].Contains ("Position")) {

            Transform target = GameObject.Find ("mallet Opponent").transform;

            float posX = System.Convert.ToSingle (slice [1]);
            float posZ = System.Convert.ToSingle (slice [2]);

            Vector3 newpos = new Vector3 (-(posX), 0, -(posZ));

            target.position = newpos;

        }
    } 

    if (MainPlayer == false) {

        if (slice [0].Contains ("Position")) { 

            Transform target = GameObject.Find ("mallet Opponent").transform;

            float posX = System.Convert.ToSingle (slice [1]);
            float posZ = System.Convert.ToSingle (slice [2]);

            Vector3 newpos = new Vector3 (-(posX), 0, -(posZ));

            target.position = newpos;

        }

        if (slice [0].Contains ("palletPosition")) {

            Transform palletTarget = GameObject.Find ("pallet").transform;

            float palletPosX = System.Convert.ToSingle (slice [1]);
            float palletPosZ = System.Convert.ToSingle (slice [2]);

            Vector3 palletNewPos = new Vector3 (-(palletPosX), 0, -(palletPosZ));

            palletTarget.position = palletNewPos;

        }

    }

}
```

So when the game starts, for the main player, i receive the messages of the other player, and it works fine.

But for the other player, i had a weird behavior.

The pallet did not move, it stays at his start position, but "mallet opponent" changes position to where the pallet would have to go, to the Main player actual position.

I don't know why it's doing this.

How can i fix that?

Comment: You may want to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395185) which suggested to to try sending the target position instead. Then when you receive this target position, you can try to interpolate from the current position to the target position. This will make the movement more smooth and less dependent on the network. Here's another [thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/780548/google-realtime-multiplayer-network-delay.html) which might also help.

Comment: Well even with that, my mallet opponent jumps from his position and to the pallet position instantaneously. I don't know why it's doing that, since they are not sharing their positions. And when the connection is lost, it's going back to normal.

Comment: I try to use 'Vector3.Lerp', but the movement is still not smooth... Any ideas to fix that?